# Reverse Engineering Web Applications

Tags: javascript, web, protocols, reverse-engineering

Aloha, Stackoverflow.

I frequently come across web applications, and wonder to myself, "How could I write a script/application which would interface with that?" (purely academic, not for spamming purposes!).

For example, the website Omegle; people have written Python scripts to interface with the website and run a chat without opening the browser... how? I will admit that WEB programming is not my strongest area, but I would really like to know how one could extract the protocol being used from such applications, and use this knowledge to create custom apps and tinker with the service.

So basically, how can I figure out the inner workings of a web app (ie. imeetzu.com such that I can write code to interface with it from my desktop?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 11):

You'll need a set of tools to start with:

- A browser with a debugging window (Chrome is particularly good for this). This will allow you in particular to access the network calls that your browser *directly* makes (there's a caveat coming), and to see:

  - their content
  - their parameters
  - their target
- A network packet sniffer to trace down anything that goes through Flash (or WebSockets). I'm quite fond of Ethereal (now called Wireshark), though if you're in the US, you could be breaking the law by using it (depends on the use you make of it). This will allow you to see every TCP frame that enters and leaves your network interface.

The knowledge you will need:

- Ability to identify and isolate a network stream. This comes through practice
- Knowledge of the language the app you are trying to reverse-engineer is written in. If JavaScript isn't your cup of tea, avoid JS-based stuff
- Maths and cryptography. Data may very well be encrypted/obfuscated/stegg-ed from time to time. Be aware and look out for it.

In this particular case, looks like you might have to deal with Flash. There are additional resources to help on this, although all of them are non-free. There is one particularly good Flash decompiler called [SoThink SWF decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/), which allows you to turn a SWF into a FLA or a collection of AS sources.

That's all for the tools. The method is easy - look what data comes in/out and figure out by elimination what is what. If it's encrypted, you'll need IVs and samples to hope to break it (or just decompile the code and find how the key/handshake is done). This is a very, very extensive field and I haven't even touched the tip of the iceberg with this - feel free to ask for more info.

(How do I know all this? I was a contributor to the eAthena project, which reverse-engineered a game protocol)